# Atomic Read and Write with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, transactions

I have two different processes (on different machines) that are reading and updating a database record.

The rule I need to ensure is that the record must only be updated if the value of it, lets say is "Initial". Also, after the commit I would want to know if it actually got updated from the current process or not (in case if value was other than initial)

Now, the below code performs something like:

```
var record = context.Records
             .Where(r => (r.id == id && r.State == "Initial"))
             .FirstOrDefault();

if(record != null) {
  record.State = "Second";
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now couple of questions

1) From looking at the code it appears that after the record is fetched with state  "Initial", some other process could have updated it to state "Second" before this process performs SaveChanges. 
In this case we are unnecessarily overwriting the state to the same value. Is this the case happening here ?

2) If case 1 is not what happens then EntityFramework may be translating the above to something like

```
update Record set State = "Second" where Id = someid and State = "Initial"
```

and performing this as a transaction. This way only one process writes the value. Is this the case with EF default TransactionScope ?

In both cases again how do I know for sure that the update was made from my process as opposed to some other process ?

If this were in-memory objects then in code it would translate to something like assuming multiple threads accessing same data structure

```
Record rec = FindRecordById(id);
lock (someobject)
{
    if(rec.State == "Initial")
       {
          rec.State = "Second";
          //Now, that I know I updated it I can do some processing
       }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you are looking for concurrency handling in EntityFramework. Technically you can add a rowversion column to your database table, obtain that value for one record when accessing it, and check that value against the latest value to see if there is any update to the record occurred outside. However that's what you manually do it, in EF you just need to turn on the Concurrency mode to **Fixed** for the rowversion property and try handling an exception (place `SaveChanges` between try-catch), a common exception of this kind is `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`.

Comment: So basically, read the value then set and save the value. If the value was changed between reading and writing DbUpdateConcurrencyException will be thrown in which I can refresh the value to examine what it got updated to ?

Comment: @Frank: Yes, that's how EF supports optimistic locking.  In contrast, attempting to lock a row to prevent someone else from updating it while you work on it, is called pessimistic locking, and is not natively supported by EF, afaik.

Comment: Without using Fixed mode, basically if the state is updated between read and write, EF will not generate any exception then ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In general there are 2 main concurrency patterns that can be used:

- **Pessimistic concurrency**: You lock a row to prevent others from unexpectedly changing the data you are currently attempting to update. EF does *not* provide any native support for this type of concurrency pattern.
- **Optimistic concurrency**: Citing from [EF's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904): *"Optimistic concurrency involves optimistically attempting to save your entity to the database in the hope that the data there has not changed since the entity was loaded. If it turns out that the data has changed then an exception is thrown and you must resolve the conflict before attempting to save again."* This pattern is supported by EF, and can be used rather simply.

Focusing on the optimistic concurrency option, which EF does support, let's compare how your example behaves with and without EF's optimistic concurrency control handling. I'll assume you are using SQL Server.

### No concurrency control

Let's start with the following script in the database:

```sql
create table Record (
  Id int identity not null primary key,
  State varchar(50) not null
)

insert into Record (State) values ('Initial')
```

And here is the code with the `DbContext` and `Record` entity:

```cs
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    static MyDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
    }

    public MyDbContext() : base(@"Server=localhost;Database=eftest;Trusted_Connection=True;") { }

    public DbSet<Record> Records { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Record.Configuration());
    }
}

public class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public class Configuration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Record>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

            this.Property(t => t.State)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsRequired();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, let's test your concurrent update scenario with the following code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var record = context.Records
            .Where(r => r.Id == 1 && r.State == "Initial")
            .Single();

        // Insert sneaky update from a different context.
        using (var sneakyContext = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var sneakyRecord = sneakyContext.Records
                .Where(r => r.Id == 1 && r.State == "Initial")
                .Single();

            sneakyRecord.State = "Sneaky Update";
            sneakyContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        // attempt to update row that has just been updated and committed by the sneaky context.
        record.State = "Second";
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

If you trace the SQL, you will see that the `update` statement looks like this:

```sql
UPDATE [dbo].[Record]
SET [State] = 'Second'
WHERE ([Id] = 1)
```

So, in effect, it doesn't care that another transaction sneaked in an update. It just blindly writes over whatever the other update did. And so, the final value of `State` in the database for that row is `'Second'`.

### Optimistic concurrency control

Let's adjust our initial SQL script to include a concurrency control column to our table:

```sql
create table Record (
  Id int identity not null primary key,
  State varchar(50) not null,
  Concurrency timestamp not null -- add this row versioning column
)

insert into Record (State) values ('Initial')
```

Let's also adjust our `Record` entity class (the `DbContext` class stays the same):

```cs
public class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    // Add this property.
    public byte[] Concurrency { get; set; }

    public class Configuration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Record>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

            this.Property(t => t.State)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsRequired();

            // Add this config to tell EF that this
            // property/column should be used for 
            // concurrency checking.
            this.Property(t => t.Concurrency)
                .IsRowVersion();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if we try to re-run the same `Main()` method we used for the previous scenario, you will notice a change in how the `update` statement is generated and executed:

```sql
UPDATE [dbo].[Record]
SET [State] = 'Second'
WHERE (([Id] = 1) AND ([Concurrency] = <byte[]>))
SELECT [Concurrency]
FROM [dbo].[Record]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = 1
```

In particular, notice how EF automatically includes the column defined for concurrency control in the `where` clause of the `update` statement.

In this case, because there was in fact a concurrent update, EF detects it, and throws a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` exception on this line:

```cs
context.SaveChanges();
```

And so, in this case, if you check the database, you'll see that the `State` value for the row in question will be `'Sneaky Update'`, because our 2nd update failed to pass the concurrency check.

### Final thoughts

As you can see, there isn't much that needs to be done to activate automatic optimistic concurrency control in EF.

Where it gets tricky though is, how do you handle the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` exception when it gets thrown?  It will largely be up to you to decide what you want to do in this case.  But for further guidance on the topic, you'll find more information here: [EF - Optimistic Concurrency Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904).

Comment: Why do the generated sql queries only have a WHERE clause on the Id and not also the state? I imagine this is maybe some EF magic assuming it's a PK and doesn't need anything else. I'm curious though what if you weren't querying by a PK, then the sneaky update should have changed the State so I imaging the second update will throw an exception since it would try to query based off the previous state "Initial" which has now been updated?

Comment: How you trace the SQL ?