# How to choose the right concurrency/locking mechanism with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, concurrency

I'm trying to implement a simple service (using C#, SQL Server, Entity Framework) that would process payments from clients, with several check happening beforehand (for example, a single product cannot be purchased more than 10 times a day, etc.)

The simplified version of the code is the following:

```
public void ExecutePayment(int productId, PaymentInfo paymentInfo)
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var stats = dbContext.PaymentStatistics.Single(s => s.ProductId== productId);
        var limits = dbContext.Limits.Single(l => l.ProductId == productId);
        int newPaymentCount = stats.DailyPaymentCount + 1;
        if (newPaymentCount > limits.MaxDailyPaymentCount)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Exceeded payment count limit");
        }

        // other limits here...

        var paymentResult = ProcessPayment(paymentInfo); <-- long operation, takes 2-3 seconds
        if (paymentResult.Success)
        {  
            stats.DailyPaymentCount = newPaymentCount;
        }

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

What I'm concerned about are possible concurrency issues. I need to make sure that no 2 threads/processes start checking/updating `stats.PaymentCount` simultaneously, otherwise the stats will be out of sync.

I was thinking about wrapping the whole method into a Distributed Lock (for example using [this implementation](https://github.com/madelson/DistributedLock)) like this:

```
string lockKey = $"processing-payment-for-product-{productId}";
var myLock = new SqlDistributedLock(lockKey);
using (myLock.Acquire())
{
    ExecutePayment(productId, paymentInfo);
}
```

But the concern with this approach is that ProcessPayment is very slow (2-3 seconds), which means that any concurrent payment requests for the same product would have to wait 2-3 seconds before the limit checks can even start.

Can anyone suggest a good locking solution for this case?

Comment: Do you store payments in database also? I mean some Payment object representing pending/failed/complete payment.

Comment: @Evk, yes, SQL Server is currently the only storage mechanism for all kinds of application data

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a lock for each transaction (Pessimistic Concurrency) - you might be better off using Optimistic Concurrency for checking `DailyPaymentCount`.

Using raw SQL (since atomic increments are hard in EF) - column names assumed:

```
// Atomically increment dailyPaymentCount. Fail if we're over the limit.
private string incrementQuery = @"UPDATE PaymentStatistics p 
                SET dailyPaymentCount = dailyPaymentCount + 1 
                FROM PaymentStatistics p 
                JOIN Limits l on p.productId = l.productId 
                WHERE p.dailyPaymentCount < l.maxDailyPaymentCount 
                AND p.productId = @givenProductId";

// Atomically decrement dailyPaymentCount
private string decrementQuery = @"UPDATE PaymentStatistics p 
                SET dailyPaymentCount = dailyPaymentCount - 1 
                FROM PaymentStatistics p 
                WHERE p.productId = @givenProductId";

public void ExecutePayment(int productId, PaymentInfo paymentInfo)
{
    using (var dbContext = MyDbContext()) {

        using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
        {
            // Try to increment the payment statistics for the given product
            var rowsUpdated = dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(incrementQuery, new SqlParameter("@givenProductId", productId));

            if (rowsUpdated == 0) // If no rows were updated - we're out of stock (or the product/limit doesn't exist)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Out of stock!");

            // Note: there's a risk of our stats being out of sync if the program crashes after this point
            var paymentResult = ProcessPayment(paymentInfo); // long operation, takes 2-3 seconds

            if (!paymentResult.Success)
            {  
                dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(decrementQuery, new SqlParameter("@givenProductId", productId));
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

This is effectively including "*in flight*" payments for a particular product in your stats - and using that as a barrier. Before processing a payment - attempt to (atomically) increment your stats - and fail the payment if `productsSold + paymentsPending > stock`. If a payment fails, decrement `paymentsPending` - which would allow subsequent payment requests to succeed.

As mentioned in the comments - there's a risk of stats being out of sync with processed payments if the payment fails, and the application crashes before dailyPaymentCount can be decremented. If this is an issue (i.e. you can't rebuild statistics on application restart) - you could use a RepeatableRead transaction which would be rolled back in the event of an application crash - but then you're back to only being able to process on payment per productId simultaneously since the PaymentStatistic row for a product will be locked after it's incremented - until the end of the transaction. This is kind of unavoidable - you can't process payments until you know you've got stock, and you won't know for sure whether or not you have stock until you've processed/failed in-flight payments.

There's a good overview of optimistic/pessimistic concurrency in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32262234/1657432).

Comment: The bit about "a RepeatableRead transaction" is somewhat confusing. Any transaction isolation level will lock the PaymentStatistic row after the increment. It is not necessary to have RepeatableRead in order to lock and then commit/rollback.

Comment: Correct, but you want to make sure that another thread doesn't read the old value of the PaymentStatistic row, and start processing payment